# Populate the field in the HTML based on the text beside it using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am newbie to Selenium and trying to explore it. I am trying to populate the field in the HTML based on the text beside it.

For example in the below image, If I have to enter "Jack" as the First name in the text box, I must be able to search the HTML file for the text "First name:" and populate the text field beside it.

[image: HTML Form]

HTML Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form>
  First name: 
  <input type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  <br>
  Last name:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" >
  <br>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I understand it is possible if "First name:" is a label, we can use

```
  selenium.type("css=label:contains(\"First name:\")+input", "Jack");
```

But the tricky part it is not necessary a label it can be any form such as

```
 <h1>,<b>,<p> or even without any tags.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @guy! I included the code. But I need a solution that is not particular to this HTML code. I am looking for a more generic solution where I can fill in a text box beside any kind of text (Text specified within any tags like <p> or <h> or <label> or even when there are no tags like the one in the above example) .

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like you need to open up the html and take a look at what you're working with.

A good tool to use is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox browser, which allows you to easily select web elements and inspect them.

With Firebug, all you would need to do is right click the element you wish to inspect, and than click "Inspect with Firebug". Firebug will then highlight and point out the exact location of the web element within the HTML, allowing you to know what tag it may fall under.

Other than that, you could post the HTML of those fields and get some starting pointers on how you should write them into your tests.

Comment: Thanks @jagdpanzer! I included the code to the question. As mentioned in the post, I am looking for a  solution that is not particular to this HTML code. I need it to be a more generic solution where I can fill in a text box beside any kind of text (Text specified within any tags like <p> or <h> or <label> or even when there are no tags like the one in the above example) .